# GKE: Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' but permissions are there?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pulumi

When attempting to create a GKE cluster via gcloud, web console, or pulumi I'm receiving the error: `Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get`.

The permission for this account have `Owner`, `Editor`, and `Compute Admin`. Testing for `compute.networks.get` using the troubleshooter also shows that it is good.

Not sure why this is happening. It seemed to have been working fine the day before.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I can also run `gcloud compute regions describe us-east1 --project=myproj` as well as the list command without issue so something is not adding up.

Edit 2:
Full error is:

`googleapi: Error 403: Retry budget exhausted (5 attempts): Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/myproj/regions/us-central1'., forbidden`

Comment: It may be related to this current issue with GKE cluster creation:
https://status.cloud.google.com//incident/container-engine/21004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a service account was deleted and disabling/enabling the service fixed the issue.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1054198/gke-google-compute-engine-required-compute-networks-get-but-permissions-are